# Zariski topology - closed sets of $\mathbb{A}_\mathbb{C}^2$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, zariski-topology

I have to prove that:

> The closed sets in Zariski topology of $\mathbb{A}_\mathbb{C}^2$ are the sets of form $Z(g)\cup F$, where $g\in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ and $F$ is a finite set.

So, I thinked the following:

We have $Z(\langle g,f\rangle)=Z(\langle g\rangle +\langle f\rangle )=Z(g)\cap  Z(f)$.

Note that we have two options:

1) There's a polynomial $m_{(g,f)}$ with degree $>0$ s.t. this is a "maximal divisor common" of $g$ and $f$. So, $g=m_{(g,f)}g_1$ and $f=m_{(g,f)}f_1$, where  there's not a polynomial $m_{(g_1,f_1)}$ with degree $>0$ s.t. this is a "maximal divisor common" of $g_1$ and $f_1$ (ie, they are relatively irreducible).So $Z(g)\cap  Z(f)=Z(m_{(g,f)}\langle g_1,f_1\rangle)=Z(m_{(g,f)})\cup (Z(g_1)\cap Z(f_1))$.

2) There's not a polynomial $m_{(g,f)}$ with degree $>0$ s.t. this is a "maximal divisor common" of $g$ and $f$ (ie, they are relatively irreducible). So, the zeros of the two are at most the product of the degrees (intersections of curves), so finite.

In any case, $Z(\langle g,f\rangle)=Z(h)+F$. The completely answer is by induction.

Is it correct?

I have doubts at language and also at this point:
Is it possible determine (or at least know the existence) of some set $S$ of polynomials s.t. $Z(S)=F$ for given $F$?

Many thanks!

Comment: I think you're on the right track, but I'm not sure what your induction is over. Not every ideal $I \subseteq \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ is generated by two polynomials. For example, $(x^3y, xy^3, x^2y^2)$ must have at least 3 generators, which you can prove by considering the degrees of elements in this ideal.

Comment: Towards your second question, you have shown that any $F$ is a union of some curve $Z(g)$ and some finite number of points. You also seem to know the relationships between ideals, their sums, their products, and the zero sets defined. Do you know the Nullstellensatz? That should help identify the ideal of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ that corresponds to a closed point $(a, b) \in \mathbb{A}_\mathbb{C}^2$.

Comment: The induction was over the number of generators, is it OK? Now I understood the second question, many thanks!